# How can I get a function to return all the images within a folder for other functions to use with IronPython?

Tags: python, function, directory, ironpython

I have some code that works fine to make a tabbed picture viewer that has the right amount of tabs only when the path to each image is individually set. I would like it to get all the images within a folder without having to write a line for each one,

```
pathToFile1 = (r'C:\Users\...\Desktop\one.jpg')
pathToFile2 = (r'C:\Users\...\Desktop\two.jpg')
pathToFile3 = (r'C:\Users\...\Desktop\three.jpg')
```

then later use

```
def setupImages(self):
    return [
            Image.FromFile(pathToFile1),
            Image.FromFile(pathToFile2),
            Image.FromFile(pathToFile3),
        ]
```

And later use the following function...

```
def setupPanel(self, parent):
     tabControl = TabControl()
     tabControl.Dock = DockStyle.Fill
     tabControl.Alignment = TabAlignment.Bottom
     for i in range(3):
         tabPage = TabPage()
         tabPage.Text = 'Image %s' % i
         tabPage.Controls.Add(self.getPictureBox(self.images[i])
         tabControl.TabPages.Add(tabPage)
     parent.Controls.Add(tabControl)
```

Full code using Artog's setupImages function.

```
import clr
clr.AddReference('System.Windows.Forms')
clr.AddReference('System.Drawing')
from os import listdir
from os.path import isfile, join
from System.Drawing import Image
from System.Windows.Forms import (
    Application, DockStyle, Form, Orientation, PictureBox,
    PictureBoxSizeMode, SplitContainer,
    TabAlignment, TabControl, TabPage
)



class MainForm(Form):
    def __init__(self):

        Form.__init__(self)
        self.images = self.setupImages() 
        splitter = SplitContainer()
        splitter.Orientation = Orientation.Vertical
        splitter.Dock = DockStyle.Fill

        def SwapOrientation(sender, event):
            if sender.Orientation == Orientation.Vertical:
                sender.Orientation = Orientation.Horizontal
            else:
                sender.Orientation = Orientation.Vertical

            splitter.DoubleClick += SwapOrientation
            self.setupPanel(splitter.Panel1)
            self.setupPanel(splitter.Panel2)
            self.Controls.Add(splitter)
            self.Text = 'Xaar Rogues Gallery'
            self.Show()

    def setupImages(self):
        mypath = (r'C:\Users\priper\Desktop\RoguesGalleryImages') # No 
        need to wrap with ()
        valid_file_endings = ['jpg','png','jpeg'] # Add / remove as needed

        # Best to start variable names with lower case, so as not to 
        confuse with classes
        image_filenames = [ 
            Image.FromFile(f) for f in listdir(mypath) 
            if isfile(join(mypath, f)) 
            and f[-3:] in valid_file_endings # check if last three 
            characters of filename is in the list of valid endings
         ]
        # print len(image_filenames)
        # print(image_filenames)
        return image_filenames 

    def getPictureBox(self, image):
        pictureBox = PictureBox()
        pictureBox.SizeMode = PictureBoxSizeMode.StretchImage
        pictureBox.Image = image
        pictureBox.Dock = DockStyle.Fill
        return pictureBox

    def setupPanel(self, parent):
        tabControl = TabControl()
        tabControl.Dock = DockStyle.Fill
        tabControl.Alignment = TabAlignment.Bottom
        for i in range(3):
            tabPage = TabPage()
            tabPage.Text = 'Image %s' % i
            tabPage.Controls.Add(self.getPictureBox(self.images[i]))
            tabControl.TabPages.Add(tabPage)
        parent.Controls.Add(tabControl)

Application.EnableVisualStyles()
form = MainForm()
Application.Run(form)
```

The code to automatically get the images in the folder without them needing to be individually hard coded, it would be great if there was a way to automatically name the tabs with the image names.

Comment: you're already using `os.listdir`why not use again?

Comment: I've struggled to get this far, i'm lost now.

Comment: You've done great, only thing that seems to be missing is a check for image file endings

Comment: That folder should only hold images so I wasnt too worried about that, what i don't know how to do is get the path into the setupImages function, mind is total fog now :-s

Comment: Well, either you just use `ImageFilenames` as you are using `pathToFile1`. or you do the listdir-logic inside the function

Comment: My suggestion is move the logic, no need to have if in the global scope

Comment: import os
files=[]
for file in os.listdir('C:\Users\priper\Desktop\RoguesGalleryImages'):
    if file.endswith('.jpg'):
        files.append(os.path.join('C:\Users\priper\Desktop\RoguesGalleryImages', file))
        print(os.path.join('C:\Users\priper\Desktop\RoguesGalleryImages', file))

Comment: I'll see if i can work something out from that, thenk you Artog

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have the solution in your code already, as discussed in the comments. Just move the logic inside the function and you're done :)

```
def setupImages(self):
    mypath = 'C:\Users\...\Desktop\RoguesGalleryImages' # No need to wrap with ()
    valid_file_endings = ['jpg','png','jpeg'] # Add / remove as needed

    # Best to start variable names with lower case, so as not to confuse with classes
    image_filenames = [ 
        Image.FromFile(f) for f in listdir(mypath) 
        if isfile(join(mypath, f)) 
        and f[-3:] in valid_file_endings # check if last three characters of filename is in the list of valid endings
    ]
    # print len(image_filenames)
    # print(image_filenames)
    return image_filenames
```

Comment: I got this far and then the fog came     def setupImages(self):


        files=[]


        for file in os.listdir(path):
            if file.endswith('.jpg'):
                files.append(os.path.join(path, file))
                print(os.path.join(path, file))
        #print ('\n'*2)
        #print files

        return [

            Image.FromFile(pathToFile1),

            Image.FromFile(pathToFile2),

            Image.FromFile(pathToFile3),

        ]

Comment: I'm probably wrong but it looks like it only provides the string path rather than having it return an image, I am guessing this is because the original Return from setupImages was Image.FromFile(pathToFile1) and now it's just the string pathway. I tried  'return Image.FromFile(image_filenames)' and that started pointing at the line for self.images = self.setupImages() being a problem.

Comment: Oh, sorry, yea.. will edit and fix. Just missing `Image.FromFile(f)`

Comment: Hi Artog, I still cannot get it to work. I have edited the code to add your function - does it work for you? I am getting an 'IOError:[Errno 2]' for the first image in the folder. I know the image is there because an earlier iteration of this tab viewer finds it ok but only with the fixed path for each image.

Comment: You can try changing `Image.FromFile(f)` to `Image.FromFile(join(mypath, f))`